# How to select all rows containing a specific letter?

Tags: select, mysqli

Lets say I have five guys in my table called guys and their names are:

```
John
Erik
Joe
Ben
James
```

If I only want the guy with an "r" in his name, how would I write that in a SELECT?

```
SELECT * FROM guys WHERE name "contains the letter r"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pattern-matching.html)

```
SELECT * FROM guys WHERE name LIKE '%r%';
```